# How do I edit multiple elements in a list on a conditional basis?

Tags: python

An assignment I'm working on for school has tasked me with writing a script in Python that will edit a list of file names. All the files that end with the "hpp" extension must be renamed to "h".

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
```

Can this be solved using a list comparision? This is what I have so far...

```
def newfilenames(filenames):
  elements = [ "h".format(filenames) for filenames]
```

Comment: I think the word you were looking for is a 'list comprehension' - your code has quite a few issues though. If you run it, you'll not that it doesn't actually work - you'll do well to try and start over, you may get someone here to write code for you that works, but that does sort of defeat the purpose of the assignment. At any rate, a list comprehension may get you a list of names that would be correct, but you'd still have to rename the files of course, unless you're only looking for the list of correct names.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your result by doing:

```py
elements = [str(name.split('.')[0] + '.h') for name in filenames if name.endswith('.hpp')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
aa = [ff.replace('hpp', 'h') for ff in filenames]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This helps

`>>[i.replace('hpp','h') if 'hpp' in i else i for i in filenames ]
['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'h.out']`

Answer (score 0):

```
def newfilenames(filenames:list):
    if not filenames:
        return filenames
    for i in range(len(filenames)):
        if filenames[i].endswith('.hpp'):
            filenames[i] = filenames[i][:-4] + '.h'
    return filenames
```